# Google maps sdk for ios - is there an option for styles

Tags: styles, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there a way to achieve this kind of style with Google maps?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No.

Google maps for Android and iOS use v2.  Custom styling is only available on v3.  This [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4968) has been open for nearly two years so it's unlikely to be implemented any time soon.

Your only option is to use [javascript styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) and wrap it up as a web-view or look at another map provider like MapBox

Answer (score 0):

Google [launched](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/09/custom-map-styling-with-google-maps.html) styled maps for [iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases) along with a new [styling wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) that allows you to apply the same style across all different platforms, including Maps JavaScript API and Static Maps. There are even some new [code](https://github.com/googlemaps/maps-sdk-for-ios-samples/blob/master/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsDemos/Samples/StyledMapViewController.m) and [style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/hiding-features) samples available for iOS.